# Getting the Current controller and action sent to the Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, controller, action

I am attempting to Get the current controller and action being called in the route. In my Global.asax.cs I have the following using and the following line:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using IProwlAdminUI.Models;

*** LINE WITH ISSUE***
string action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
*******
```

Right now the ViewContext.RouteData is giving me "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext.RouteData.Get'"

I need to get this so that I can use the controller and action to evaluate permissions for the user and see if they can perform the action they are attempting to do.

Any Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That is the wrong way to customize ASP.NET MVC authentication. [Don't do it.](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/09/38390/)

Comment: The right way, incidentally, is to use ASP.NET membership and role providers combined with `AuthorizeAttribute` . This is explained in more detail in my link.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you are trying to do because the code in Global.asax executes only once when your application starts up. This happens before the context of an incoming request is available and that is why you cannot access the RouteData values.

On a more general note, you can write a custom AuthorizationAttribute to do what you want. See the following link for an example: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/09/CustomAuthorizationASPNETMVCFrameworkAuthorizeAttribute.aspx