# How do you extract parameters from an MVC URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, parameters

I have a URL route of "ticket/{ticket_guid}/{controller}/{action}/{id}".  Normally, the parameters would be parsed for you and passed as parameters to the controller action.  I need to get access to the {ticket_guid} parameter from inside the Global.asax's Application_AuthenticateRequest event handler.  What is the best way to parse out the ticket_guid parameter?

Comment: "MVC" is a generic concept. What language/framework are you using?

Comment: @Mike, I think he means ASP.Net MVC

Comment: I am using asp.net.  sorry for not giving the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this (if I have correctly assumed ASP.Net MVC):

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["ticket_guid"].ToString()
```

Comment: The ViewContext object doesn't seem to be available at this point.  I get a design-time error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext.RouteData.get'

Comment: I skipped over the Global.asax part, [you might not be able to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258503/getting-the-current-controller-and-action-sent-to-the-route/3258574#3258574)